# SmartAssembly memory management

Tags: .net, memory-management, obfuscation

Just came across [this website](http://www.smartassembly.com/product/index.aspx). Feature 9 is memory management and they claim that their product "automatically releas[es] memory [that is] no longer needed."

Is this a marketing ploy, or do you think they have some trick up their sleeves? Are they just making a claim based on what they .Net runtime provides in any case (or are they *gasp* calling GC.Collect())?

Not really interested in the product, DotFuscator suffices for me - I am just *really* interested on how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting.

A [review from 2007](http://neosmart.net/blog/2007/smartassembly/) contains this:

> {smartassembly} uses several different
>   techniques to bring down the memory
>   usage.
>
> We asked the developers of
>   {smartassembly} for some of the
>   specifics, and they told us that by
>   default the CLR reserves a ton of
>   memory for .NET assemblies - whether
>   or not they request it. So
>   {smartassembly} intelligently detects
>   when the CPU is idle (or thereabout)
>   and increases or decreases the amount
>   of reserved memory for your assembly
>   according to its requirements -
>   "automated" GC in a sense, except that
>   memory may or may not have ever been
>   in use.
>
> In that same vein, {smartassembly}
>   (with the benefit of literally having
>   access to your source code thanks to
>   the way .NET is designed) marks any
>   and all classes that don't have any
>   detectable "child" classes inheriting
>   from them as "sealed" thereby reducing
>   the amount of memory and CPU used by
>   the CLR during run-time to determine
>   what functions should be made
>   available to other classes and
>   libraries.

The same review has a "before/after" pair of screenshots showing an application going from 8M to 420K. This suggests to me that it's actually just reducing the working set of the application, not the real memory requirements. The same "optimisation" appears to occur if you minimise an app. It doesn't suddenly take up less memory. I don't believe the desktop .NET framework can *really* run with only 420K.

The automatic sealing feature is interesting - I can't see that it helps other than for lookup of virtual methods. I doubt that the impact is really significant, but of course I haven't benchmarked it.

So, nothing conclusive, but I doubt that it's doing anything that I'd particularly want.

Comment: Come to think about it this is a really bad idea. Think about a server which sits idle for 3 hours, SmartAssembly reduces it working set and suddenly you get a spike of users, .Net will have to reallocate all that memory. People should probably trust Microsoft :). I wonder if it runs on Mono as well

Comment: This is really a bad idea. In the past we used the "memory optimization" feature and in clients that used Terminal Services (10+ user sessions in the same machine using our desktop app) this has a severe performance penalty because the disk could not keep up with the amount of page faults and swap acess...

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that SmartAssembly pushes the data to page file. If in task manager you select the columns CommitSize and PF delta you will see that although the WorkingSet reduces size, the commit size stays almost the same. If you then try to access something in your application you will see lots of page faults.

If this is the behavior of "Memory optimization" then I think the name does not fit the feature and it should simply be called "De-optimization" as the cost of accessing the page file could significantly reduce performance.

Am I wrong with this interpretation?